# block special character validation on submit button

Tags: javascript, jsp

I tried with this code to allow the copy and paste in text box and validate it on submit button.But it is not working.Anyone wants to suggest something would be appreciated.

```
$('#businessId').bind('keypress', function(e) {
     blockSpecialCharacter(e);
   });

   var regex = new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$");
    function blockSpecialCharacter(event) {
      var key = String.fromCharCode(!event.charCode ? event.which : event.charCode);
      if (!regex.test(key)) {
         event.preventDefault();
         return false;
      }
    }




function blockPaste(event) {
  var pastedData = event.originalEvent.clipboardData.getData('text/plain');
  if (!regex.test(pastedData)) {
     event.preventDefault();
     return false;
  }
}

<div class="buttons">
      <input type="submit" onclick="return blockPaste(e);" value="<spring:message code="button.save" />" />
      <input type="submit" value="<spring:message code="button.cancel" />" name="_cancel"/>
</div>
```

Comment: Its better to use change event instead of keypress. because change will be activated on copy paste too.

Comment: nope not working

Comment: you need to share your whole code.